# How to separate persistance in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, persistence, abstraction, rails-activerecord

I'm currently builing an application in Ruby (not Rails) which uses ActiveRecord as an ORM and sqlite as a database.

A sample code, just to clarify my question:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :logins, :foreign_key => :user_id
  has_many :categories, :foreign_key => :user_id
  has_many :news, :foreign_key => :user_id
  has_many :settings, :foreign_key => :user_id

  class << self
    def get_user_by_id(id)
      find(id)
    end

    def insert(username, password)
      create(:username => username, :password => password)
    end
  end
end
```

The code (relations, models, etc.) is not complicated at all for now. However, when my models start to get bigger I don't want to mix business logic and persistence logic in the same classes. I want to be able to change my persistence method (files, in-memory, other database orm). Is there an established way to to this? I read that in Rails it's common to have "skinny controllers, fat models", but I'm looking for a way around this.

Comment: What about using Rails and letting it do all that for you?

Comment: More precisely, it seems like Rails-3 new [ActiveModel](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/3_0_release_notes.html#orm-abstraction-and-action-pack-interface) concept is right for it: ORM abstraction.

Comment: Because I'm building a non-rails application and I want to use only ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the ActiveRecord pattern might not be the best solution for your situation. [The definition of the Active Record pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) says:

> An object carries both data and behavior. Much of this data is
>   persistent and needs to be stored in a database. Active Record uses
>   the most obvious approach, putting data access logic in the domain
>   object. This way all people know how to read and write their data to
>   and from the database.

Perhaps you might want to look into the Data Mapper pattern (and the [Data Mapper ORM](http://datamapper.org/)), which is desgned specifically to separate business logic and persistence.

That said, if you must really use ActiveRecord, I'd throw in some composition, something like:

```
class UserRepository < ActiveRecord::Base
  # all the persistence stuff goes in here
end

class User
  def initialize(login, repository=UserRepository)
    @repository = repository
    @user = @repository.find_by_login(login)
  end

  def instanography
    #complicated business logic
  end

  def method_missing(m, *args, &block)
    @user.send(m, *args, &block)
  end
end
```

As illustrated in the example above, I'd make a User object act as a proxy to the real active record object, keeping all the business logic and concealing the persistence stuff.